# Error in using amcl

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use amcl for localization of my robot from a pre-saved map. I am using a Hokuyo laser range finder. My command to start amcl is as below:

```
rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node
rosrun map_server map_server test.yaml
rosrun robot_setup_tf tf_broadcaster
rosrun amcl amcl
```

However, what I got is the warning code as below:

```
[ WARN] [1392274402.961608347]: Message from [/hokuyo_node] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [laser]. Resolved locally to [/laser].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1392274417.844748520]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1392274417.844651 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
[ WARN] [1392274417.845193549]: Message Filter [target=/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.amcl.message_notifier] ros console logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

I have tried to run the amcl with both scan:=/scan and scan:=/base_scan before and the tf broadcaster transform the laser frame to base frame. I don't seems to see anything when I echoed amcl_pose. May I know what do I lack in running amcl? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128821/error-in-using-amcl/) by [zero1985](https://answers.ros.org/users/6926/zero1985/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-02-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The key error message here is:

```
[ WARN] [1392274417.845193549]: Message Filter [target=/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.amcl.message_notifier] ros console logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

What this means is that AMCL is trying to transform laser scans from their incoming frame into the /odom frame and failing because a transform from the laser frame to the odom frame doesn't exist.

You should probably be either running a driver for your robot that publishes odometry as a trasform from the /odom frame to the /base_link frame, or you can try lowering AMCL's reliance on odometry and publishing a static transform from the /odom frame directly to your laser frame.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zero1985](https://answers.ros.org/users/6926/zero1985/) on 2014-02-17**:
Thank you for your answer. I think I got it, but the amcl_pose only update when I input a initial pose for it. After that the pose is not updated when I move my robot. Is it correct?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-17**:
AMCL only updates when it thinks your robot has moved. You may want to try setting the update_min_d and update_min_a parameters to 0, or providing fake odometry via the laser_scan_matcher node.